# Por que não consigo definir o valor do input com o innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>aula</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script>
      function troca() {
        var A = document.getElementById('a').value
        var B = document.getElementById('b').value

        var C = A
        A = B
        B = C

        document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = A
        document.getElementById('b').innerHTML = B
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="a" />
      <input type="text" id="b" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="troca" onclick="troca()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Como vocês podem ver, na hora que disparo a função, os campos deviam trocar de posição. Mas, isso não ocorre e não encontro o erro.

Answer (score 0):

O que ocorre é que está a usar o atributo de `innerHTML` ao invés de `value`. O que você quer é definir o valor de um `<input>`. Neste caso, você deve usar o atributo de `value`, como é documentado em https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-value e também em https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement.

Sobre o `<input>`:

> The input control's value. When specified in the HTML, this is the initial value, and from then on it can be altered or retrieved at any time using JavaScript to access the respective HTMLInputElement object's value property.

Sobre o `HTMLInputElement`:

> Current value in the control.

Em outras palavras, se você quer mudar o valor ou obter o valor utilize o `value`.

Inclusive, no seu código, você usa isso no inicio, como:

```
var A = document.getElementById('a').value
```

Mas, por algum motivo, você decidiu usar `innerHTML`para definir o valor:

```
document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = A
```

O que deve fazer, é o que você já havia feito, ou seja:

```
document.getElementById('a').value = A
```

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>aula</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script>
      function troca() {
        var A = document.getElementById('a').value
        var B = document.getElementById('b').value

        var C = A
        A = B
        B = C

        document.getElementById('a').value = A
        document.getElementById('b').value = B
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="a" />
      <input type="text" id="b" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="troca" onclick="troca()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: comentário adicional: tem uma exceção que usa innerHTML que é o campo <textarea>, demais usam .value

Comment: assim valeu, eu usei o innerhtml eu outro exercício ai achei que ia ser da mesma forma.. mais obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @wkrueger Como assim? `textarea` também tem `value`: [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement#properties) | [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#htmltextareaelement) - por fim, usar `value` ou `innerHTML` pode dar diferença em alguns casos ([exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50762645))